# JavaScript - Filter Nested Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to filter an array in javascript, and am struggling when the array is nested.

At the moment, the furthest I've been able to get is filtering a flat array:

```
var ID = 3

var arr = [{ id : 1, name: "a" }, { id : 2, name: "b" }, { id : 3, name: "c" }]

var result = arr.filter(function( obj ) {return obj.id == ID;});
alert(result[0].name);
```

Though the above doesn't work if the array looks like this instead:

```
var arr2 = [
    [{ id : 1, name: "a" },{ id : 2, name: "b" }],
    [{ id : 3, name: "c" },{ id : 4, name: "d" }]
]
```

The two examples can be found: https://jsfiddle.net/vjt45xv4/

Any tips for finding the appropriate result on the nested array would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If the array looks like that instead, what do you want the result to be? (Or do you only ever want to find one object?)

Comment: Apply the same filter you are using on your `arr` to each item in `arr2` (since items in `arr2` are arrays themselves)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Flatten](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Flatten_an_array_of_arrays) the array then **filter** it:

```
arr.reduce(function(a,b) { return a.concat(b);  })
   .filter(function(obj) { return obj.id == ID; });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
arr2.filter(function(obj) {

  obj.filter(function(d) { 

    if(d.id == ID) { 

      result = d;

    }

  })

});

alert(result.name);
```

Hope this is what you were looking for. Rather than flattening the data here I went into the nested array till the point where it was flat(and matching) and set the result there.

```
arr2.forEach(function(d) {

  d.forEach(

    function(dd){ 

      alert(dd.id);

      if (dd.id==ID){

        result=dd; 

      }

    }

  );

});

alert(result.name);
```

Edit: As minitech mentioned its same working if just using forEach.

Comment: If you’re going to assign to a variable, why not just use `forEach`?

Comment: Yep no argument there it can be done ! Besides I guess the way John Strickler mentioned is correct way if not looking for workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question from perhaps a similar problem:

I have a data structure such as this:

```
x.suites[0].specs[0].tests[0].results[0].status == "skipped"
```

My goal was to flag all of the non [skipped/ignored/???] status localed somewhere deep in this structure.

I came up with this solution:

```
var ignoreStatus = ["skipped"];
x.suites
.forEach( (xsuit)=> { xsuit.specs
    .forEach( (xspec)=> { xspec.tests
        .forEach( (xtst)=> { 
                var arry=xtst.results.filter((ftst)=>{ 
                    return !ignoreStatus.includes(ftst.status)
                });
                if(arry.length>0){ 
                    console.log(`!!!Flag this:${arry}`) 
                } else { 
                    console.log("ignored:" ,xtst.results.map(m=>{return m.status}).join("/") ); 
                } 
                
        })
    })
})
```