# How to filter nested array while filtering an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Given the example structure,

```
const selectedEdges = [
    { id: 'e1', start: 'n2', end: 'n1' },
    { id: 'e3', start: 'n6', end: 'n2' },
]
```

How do I compare nested array (`nestedNodeNodeIds`) with a plain array and the object

```
const nestedNodeIds = [['n1', 'n2'], ['n6']]
selectedEdges
  .filter(({ start, end }) => !nestedNodeIds.includes(start) || !nestedNodeIds.includes(end)))
  .filter(Boolean);
```

and return `[{ id: 'e3', start: 'n6', end: 'n2' }]`...??

It's returning `[{ id: 'e1', start: 'n2', end: 'n1' }, { id: 'e3', start: 'n6', end: 'n2' }]`

Comment: `includes()` comapres object references. Since `nestedNodeIds` is initialized with two array literals, they're not gonna match anything in `edgeById`. Also a string doesn't have the properties `start` and `end`, so I'm guessing your definition of `selectedEdges` is incorrect.

Comment: Good catch! Thanks! I edited it

Comment: This is a pretty complex problem. Must be a big challenge @PatrickRoberts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript - Filter Nested Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32571491/javascript-filter-nested-arrays)

Comment: No different case ;;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```js
const selectedEdges = [
  { id: "e1", start: "n2", end: "n1" },
  { id: "e3", start: "n6", end: "n2" },
];
const nestedNodeIds = [["n1", "n2"], ["n6"]];

selectedEdges
  .filter(
    ({ start, end }) =>
      nestedNodeIds.filter((x) => x.includes(start) && x.includes(end))
        .length === 0
  )
  .filter(Boolean);
```

You have to iterate over each `nestedNodeIds` sub-array and search in it.

Comment: I think it will not be optimal, as it's having O(n**2) complexity.

Comment: Yes, it's not optimal. But it returns right value: `[{"id":"e3","start":"n6","end":"n2"}]`

Comment: @hellofanengineer please, upvote and accept if you found this answer helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Just do a quick array map before comparison like that:

```js
const selectedEdges = [
    { id: 'e1', start: 'n2', end: 'n1' },
    { id: 'e3', start: 'n6', end: 'n2' },
]
const nestedNodeIds = [];
const _temp = [['n1', 'n2'], ['n6']];

_temo.map(v => {nestedNodeIds.push(...v)})  // Appending all the values in a plain array

selectedEdges
  .filter(({ start, end }) => !nestedNodeIds.includes(start) || !nestedNodeIds.includes(end)))
  .filter(Boolean);
```

Comment: This is returning `[{ id: 'e1', start: 'n2', end: 'n1' }, { id: 'e3', start: 'n6', end: 'n2' }]` 
:(

Comment: How do you wanna the answer, explain a little

Comment: That's not what he wants. You could just do `nestedNodeIds.flat()` by the way